# How to use GregorianCalendar to calculate UTC from year and day of year?

Tags: java, datetime, gregorian-calendar

Basically I got some Year, Day of Year values. I would like to calculate the UTC in minutes from these values.

I tried using GregorianCalendar, but I cant get this to work. It would be nice if I just could set the YEAR and DAY_OF_YEAR fields and then let the other fields get filled out.

Or is there andy library which could help?

Comment: I think Joda can do this. Also, it's generally superior for any date or time handling in Java.

Comment: So your input might be 32. day of 2012, and you want, as result, 1. Feb. 2012 in minutes?

Comment: Yeah, in Minutes starting 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar();
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2012);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 32);
System.out.println(gc.getTimeInMillis()/1000/60); // /1000 -> in seconds; /60-> in minutes

System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE));
System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));//months are indexed from 0
System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: Thats pretty much it. And its so embarassing simple... I thought i needed to do something, after setting some fields, to calculate the remaining fields. But apperently I dont... Thanks.